# Styling links syntax for CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

```css
.button a:link {
  color: blue;
}

.button a:visited {
  color: purple;
}

.button a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#a"><button>Cambridgeshire</button></a>
  <a href="#b"><button>Cornwall</button></a>
  <a href="#c"><button>Cumbria</button></a>
  <a href="#d"><button>Derbyshire</button></a>
  <a href="#e"><button>Devon</button></a>
</div>
```

The links do not change color when selected. I have also tried:
`btn-group a:link {color:blue}` etc. but again that wording doesn't work.
What wording should I use?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "selected links"?

Comment: Use `a:active`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Comment: @GolezTrol `a:active` is only applied after the link has already been clicked, but the target page hasn't been loaded yet, i.e. for a very short time *after* clicking a link.

Comment: You're right. [`a:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) is the one that is used when a linked is 'selected' (focused). But there is more wrong with this code.

Comment: to start with, you html is invalid: Button inside link aren't allowed

Answer (score 2):

If by  "selected" you mean that they have focus, you can add a selector for `:focus`.

Also note that your buttons are *children of the links*, not vice versa, as your CSS rules imply, so you have to turn that around; plus `button` is a *tag*, not  a *class*, therefore it shouldn't have a preceding dot in a CSS selector.

```css
a:link button {
  color: blue;
}

a:visited button {
  color: purple;
}

a:hover button {
  color: red;
}

a:focus button {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#a"><button>Cambridgeshire</button></a>
  <a href="#b"><button>Cornwall</button></a>
  <a href="#c"><button>Cumbria</button></a>
  <a href="#d"><button>Derbyshire</button></a>
  <a href="#e"><button>Devon</button></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.button` is targeting an element with a class of "button", to target an element itself you would just use `button`. It probably makes more sense to target `.btn-group` instead of applying styles to all `button`'s. It's also good to be specific, by adding that this only applies to `button` elements within `.btn-group` that are direct children of `a` tags.

You can set all the buttons within an `a` tag (:link) to be blue, and then set all buttons within an `a` tag that have been visited to be purple, and then set all buttons to be red on hover.

```css
.btn-group a:link > button {
  color: blue;
}
.btn-group a:visited > button {
  color: purple;
}
.btn-group a > button:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#a"><button>Cambridgeshire</button></a>
  <a href="#b"><button>Cornwall</button></a>
  <a href="#c"><button>Cumbria</button></a>
  <a href="#d"><button>Derbyshire</button></a>
  <a href="#e"><button>Devon</button></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is wrong. You are trying to style an element with the class `button` and you are targeting an `a` element inside of that element. You don't need the `button` elements at all.

You should target `.btn-group a`. That basically means an `a` element inside of your `.btn-group` div.

```css
.btn-group a:link {
  color: blue;
}

.btn-group a:visited {
  color: purple;
}

.btn-group a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#a">Cambridgeshire</a>
  <a href="#b">Cornwall</a>
  <a href="#c">Cumbria</a>
  <a href="#d">Derbyshire</a>
  <a href="#e">Devon</a>
</div>
```

Notes:
`:link` - Styles the link in its normal state.

`:visited` - Styles the link once it has been visited by a user

`:hover` - Styles the link as the user hovers.

`:active` - this is a temporary state as the user is actively engaging, e.g. holding down the mouse button on click.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.btn-group a:link > button {
  color: blue;
}

.btn-group a:visited > button {
  color: purple;
}

.btn-group a:hover > button{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#a"><button>Cambridgeshire</button></a>
  <a href="#b"><button>Cornwall</button></a>
  <a href="#c"><button>Cumbria</button></a>
  <a href="#d"><button>Derbyshire</button></a>
  <a href="#e"><button>Devon</button></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I know I don't *need* the buttons, but that's how I want the links to appear and not merely with the name.
It doesn't appear to make any difference whether I use

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button><a href="#a">Cambridgeshire</a></button>
<button><a href="#b">Cornwall</a></button>
<button><a href="#c">Cumbria</a></button>

or

<div class="btn-group">
<a href="#a"><button>Cambridgeshire</button></a>
<a href="#b"><button>Cornwall</button></a>
<a href="#c"><button>Cumbria</button></a>
```

I have changed the CSS to:

```
.btnn-group a:link { color: blue;
}
.btn-group a:visited { color: purple;
}
.btn-goup a:hover { color: red;
}
.btn-group a:active  { color: red;
}
```

Comment: Do not use answers to ask new questions. Open up a new question. You do not need the `button` element to make the `a` tags look like buttons. Your HTML in both examples is invalid - which makes a difference if you want to learn to code correctly.